# "TypeError: self.records.find(...) is undefined" when selecting records in multiple pages in openERP 7

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, openerp-7

In my openERP screen Im getting "TypeError: self.records.find(...) is undefined" when selecting records in multiple pages.
Im having a page with search button.If the results loaded for more than 1 page(80 records per page)and if I selected a checkbox in a page and while selecting checkbox in another page it throws an javascript error

> TypeError: self.records.find(...) is undefined

It happens only when Im selecting records in multiple pages.
What would be the reason for this?

Update:
It might be because of NULL values.But I want to know why and how to rectify this?